# MediaPlayer next and previous song functionality while using Fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a simple Android app where there are two fragments. One fragment containing the ListView having the list of songs. Second fragment has buttons to start,stop,previous song,next song functionality.

When a song is selected from the list, the link(Just the link) of that song is passed to the method implemented in Second fragment and it plays the song.

I'm not finding any way by which I can also pass the Index of the song from the list or any other way using which I can implement previous & next functionality.

I searched a lot. But couldn't find much.

*One possible solution I could think of, is pass the ListView to the Second Fragment so that It can perform next and previous functions. But that would be heavy, as each time a song is pressed, the whole ListView would be required to pass to the second fragment.*

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should show some code or explain better exactly what you are trying to do, and how you are currently doing it.

Answer (score 0):

1.How to communicate with Fragment
 [Fragment communication](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

2.Get  list of song [Example](http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html)

Comment: I know how to do these things.
I want to know what should be a good way to do this. As I don't want to modify the architecture of the app. I have control functions in second fragment. Don't want to modify it.

Comment: after getting postion from first fragment you can play with postion in 2nd fragment :)

Comment: If I just pass the position to the second fragment, then I won't be able to perform the Next and Previous functions. For that, I would need to pass the List of songs to the second fragment. But It is not an efficient idea to pass the List every time, a song is played from the first fragment, so as to perform the Next & Previous functions. I need a simple but efficient way for this.